# Overflow on Chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I was developing a site on firefox, and now it works perfect for all devices on firefox but overflows terribly on mobile chrome. I've added bright colors and red borders to help in debugging, and I'm not able to understand what causes this.

This situation is on the responsive mode and on physical devices.

Prefixes are added in my CSS via https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

html, body {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

html {
    background: green !important;
    max-height: 100vh !important;
    max-width: 100vw !important;
}

body {
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Here's how it looks on chrome
[image: Chrome]

And how it's supposed to look, on firefox.
[image: Firefox]